# Installed Ubuntu 12.10 on Macbook Pro (Late 2011) - cannot detect wireless network?

Tags: 12.10

I am as good as a beginner in Linux, and I'm sure I need to install the wireless driver for the Macbook's wireless card to pick up the wireless network.

I just don't know how.

Thanks in advance! :)

Rhys

Comment: Can you connect to a wireless network without the drivers?  Sometimes it works by default.

Answer (score 0):

You must install Ubuntu properly or you have Windows 7. It won't work with Windows 7. If you didn't install properly then [click here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation)

Comment: OP states they are using Macbook Pro (Late 2011), not Windows 7, so not sure how your reference to Windows 7 is applicable.

Comment: OP has already installed Ubuntu on their mac, so installation is not the issue. The OP is trying to use wireless. There is no reference to wifi in the post you provide, so it doesn't seem appropriate. However [this post](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro9-2/Quantal#Wireless) may help.